# CS GO displaced skins rendering

Tags: drivers, graphics, steam, tearing

Ubuntu version: 20.04

It just happen from nowhere, skins are displaced and it is unplayable.

[image]

I tried to reinstall the game via steam.

Comment: It looks like it is coming from the latest CS:GO update. I started seeing the same behavior just after that. I would be interested to know if there is a fix as well.

Comment: @silentnights Same behaviour? Is that means that it's all the time for you too ?

Comment: Yes, I started seeing it yesterday I think. It looks exactly the same as your picture and it is all the time like this now. I noticed before launching it that there was an update for CS:GO, so I assume it is coming from it.

I thought for a while that my GPU got broken. !

Comment: Same thing for me here, I tried changing settings in a lot of different ways and it doesn't fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Try to launch the game today. Apparently there is a new update that fixes the displaced graphics.

Build ID: **7877999**